# Comparing data, reporting low number and corresponding cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to compare two cells to determine the lowest number, but I need the matching name pair to follow the determined value.

To Compare the value 80(B1) and 81(B2): Report the low number to cell (B3) i am using:   =IF(B1

But then I need to corresponding adjacent cell A2 to report to A3

CHAD/WILLY  81

ROGER/STEVE 80

Roger/Steve 80

Comment: It is not clear can you provide initial data and the result corresponding to it

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=INDEX(A1:A2,MATCH(MIN(B1:B2),B1:B2,0))
```

[image]

If you have lots of data and there is more than one record with a minimum **B** value, the formula will return the *first* assocated **A** value.